# Blank Desktop after Login on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, root, disk-usage

I rebooted my system and receive a blank desktop after logging in. on getting into the shell with ctrl + alt + F1 and doing a "df" i see that my root partition is full with 100% usage.

I dont want to loose any data , how can i get my desktop back . Can someone please guide me through this.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem eventually.

so the weird part was that as soon as i deleted a few files which were a bit large enough to free off some space, the space magically got occupied again after about 30 seconds.

We finally found a large file of about 70G which were the CUPS logs. So somehow my system was acting as a print server and the CUPS daemon running in the background was eating up my space. once we disabled the CUPS daemon and prevented it from restarting on boot the problem was solved  and i had my desktop back.

Hope this helped.